PDE with multiple first-order time derivatives
I was wondering about a certain form of PDEs that I haven't come across nor could find examples online for. Namely, PDEs with 2 (or more) first-order derivatives in time. Something like:
$\partial_t U + \partial_x F(U) = \sigma \partial_t Q$,
where $\sigma$ is some coefficient, $Q = Q(U)$ and, of course, $\partial_t = \partial / \partial t$ and likewise for $\partial_x$.
If you are wondering where this is leading, it's this: How would one interpret the right-hand side term? So, if you have an idea of a similar expression involving multiple first-order temporal derivatives, that would be a nice start.

Is $Q$ a known function?

Q is a function of U, say $Q = Q(U)$. You're right, I should have added that. I'll change that.

Would usually be rewritten as $\partial_t(U-\sigma Q(U))+\partial_x F(U) = 0$.  Then you can move either partial differentiation expression to the other side for interpretation.

I would have written it as $$(1 -  \sigma Q') u_{t} + F' u_{x} = 0$$ which puts it in the 'standard' form $$a(x, y, u) u_{t} + b(x, y, u) u_{x} = c(x, y, u)$$
